# WITH CLAUSE in Netezza

Tags: netezza

Unable to use JOIN inside the WITH CLAUSE

```
WITH EmpCTE(empid, empname, mgrid, lvl)
AS
( 
  -- Anchor Member (AM)
  SELECT empid, empname, mgrid, 0
  FROM Employees
  WHERE empid = 7
  UNION ALL

  -- Recursive Member (RM)
  SELECT E.empid, E.empname, E.mgrid, M.lvl+1
  FROM Employees AS E
    JOIN EmpCTE AS M
      ON E.mgrid = M.empid
)
SELECT * FROM EmpCTE e order by e.empid
```

> ERROR [42S02] ERROR:  relation does not exist ADMIN.EMPCTE

Can some one please give alternate Solutions ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not the JOIN, but that your are referencing the CTE within its own definition.

Netezza does not currently (as of v7.2) support recursive CTE/WITH expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ...any alternate solutions?

Comment: This sort of logic will be best implemented as a stored procedure.